# What is a hooked powerlaw?

Tags: distributions, power-law, pareto-distribution, fat-tails, zipf

I happened to encounter lots of scientific/business scenarios where a Zipf/Pareto/powerlaw describes well my data. However, whenever the mean of the distribution is large enough, the fact that these distributions have infinite variance turns into unphysical results. I then found articles mentioning "hooked powerlaw" that I guess is meant to address this. What's a mathematical formulation of it? Any python/numpy code for that?

Comment: Google takes you here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/hooked-power-law-r/.

Comment: @whuber thanks but that is R code - guess I could try to understand it and post the math here/convert it to python.